# Grant access to private circle

Tags: api, oauth, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I want to use Google APIs with OAuth 2.0 for authentication / authorization.

**Is it currently possible to grant access to only people you have in a private circle?**

Basically i want to secure a place on the web. To grant google+ users access, I just drag them into a specific circle.

Comment: Need clarification: You want your app to check user A against a list of people in a user B's circles to decide whether user A is allowed access to your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built in, but you could build this. What you'd need to do was sign-in (with offline access) to your application as the 'admin', and just grant it access to that one circle. The app would have recheck the people.list every so often (using a stored refresh token), and record the latest list of users. Then, when a regular user came to sign-in, you would allow that sign-in the check against the list of stored friends before granting them access to the private area. You could even give the users who didn't have access a "let me in" button, which would share a post prefilled to share with you, so they could ask for access.

You can see how to retrieve the list of people here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_a_collection_of_people

If you didn't add friends very often, then you can make the people.list update happen when a user tried to access who wasn't part of the group, to check they hadn't been added.